# springdoc-openapi-ui How do I set the request to HTTPS

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openui

When I publish, I will use HTTPS requests instead of HTTP, but swagger original URL is still HTTP, I have no idea how to set it up, and there is no documentation for servers in the original springdoc-openapi-ui configuration

https://springdoc.org/index.html#properties
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem by modifying the Nginx configuration and the Spring-boot configuration（application.properties）

nginx-conf:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

spring-boot (`application.properties`):

```yaml
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/171

Answer (score 21):

you can try this :

```java
...
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.servers.Server;
...
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
...
}
```

more info here https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/726

Comment: The only approach that worked for me. Just setting "url = /" makes REST call relative to where you are (no need to rewrite host or anything).

Comment: spring: server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
nginx: proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Comment: Another Note, if you have a default context path you would add that to the url. For example, `@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/v1", description = "Default Server URL")})`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly improvement from the existing answers. In my situation, I have defined a `context-path` that is also used by my `traefik` reverse proxy. If I apply the above answers at explained, a `https://my.domain.com/my-context-path/api/action` is converted to `https://my.domain.com/api/action` that is wrong. Then on the `@OpenAPIDefinition` set your context path rather than `/`.

The complete configuration is:

On the `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-context-path
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

And in the `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "${server.servlet.context-path}", description = "Default Server URL")})
```

Also I need to set the `server.forward-headers-strategy=framework` as shown to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot application in Azure Services only needed this line in the `application.properties` as in the accepted answer:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy = framework
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33423047)

Answer (score 0):

For who is using CXF. I submitted an issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8685