# How do I make the swagger request be triggered by https?

Tags: java, spring, cors, swagger, railway

I published an api in SpringBoot on railway. The domain is in https, but swagger-ui triggers the request by http and I'm having CORS problem. I guess that's why, because when I try to send a GET request directly through the browser through the railway domain, I have no problems. I tried to free Cors from diverse forms that I will list below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
            .maxAge(3600); // Define o tempo máximo que o navegador deve armazenar a configuração CORS em cache (em segundos).
    }
}
```

None of these attempts above worked:

- `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")`
- `@CrossOrigin(origins = "my domain")`
- `@CrossOrigin("my domain")`

Comment: I think this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843940/springdoc-openapi-ui-how-do-i-set-the-request-to-https

Comment: Thank you buddy, the link helped me, I managed to solve the problem!